# Quick way to delete a line from an extremely large file

Tags: command-line, files, sed, csv

I have a 67GB .csv file (I know... I know...)

I need to remove the 4,125,878th line from the file as it is corrupt.  My CSV parsing tools won't ignore or skip it.

I *could* use `sed` to do something like

`sed '4125878d' in.csv > out.csv`

But that would be an hugely expensive operation in terms of time and disk space.

If I use `sed -i '4125878d' in.csv`, the operation takes ages.

Is there a way I can **quickly** remove a line from the middle of a huge file?

Comment: How do you expect the computer to know where the 4,125,878th line starts without actually reading the whole file and counting line breaks? If it's a one-time issue, just wait for it to be solved, and if you need to do this regularly, I suggest you try to fix the root cause of file corruption instead.

Comment: See my reply at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66730/is-there-a-faster-way-to-remove-a-line-given-a-line-number-from-a-file/233509#233509 where I explain how to use `ved` which is a very fast editor.

Answer (score 2):

I believe not.

Even if sed or whatever program you use for that is clever enough to do the change in place and not with a temp file, it will still have to rewrite all the data after the starting of the line you want to delete.

Deleting a line means that you are shifting left all the contents of the file from the point on, to the end of the previous line. No matter what, you will still have to rewrite the file from that point on.

Comment: `sed -i` creates and uses a tempfile.

Comment: And `sed -I` is a vendor specific non-portable extension.

Answer (score 1):

Do it on-the-fly:

```
csv-parser -f <(cat my-huge.csv | sed '4125878d')
```