# fast ways of removing beginning lines from large text file

Tags: text-processing, performance, large-files

I have a big text file (>500GB), all the ways I can find (sed/tail and others) all require write the 500GB content to disk. Is there anyway to quickly remove the first a few lines in place without writing 500GB to disk?

Comment: [There is no way to efficiently remove things from the start of a file.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25633)

Comment: Good find, don. I was about to suggest ed, but the other Q covers it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out! How about removing the last line? I see it says removing last line can be very fast, but it didn't say how. @don_crissti

Comment: Well, [if you know the size in bytes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1279) you can truncate the file. For your actual problem [there's also this approach](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66746)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` to delete lines in place with the `-i` option:

```
$ cat foo.txt
bar
baz
lorem
$ sed -i '1d' foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
baz
lorem
```

You can also delete a range of lines; for example `sed -i '1,4d' foo.txt` will remove lines 1-4.

EDIT: as don pointed out in the comments, the `-i` option still creates a copy.

Comment: This will also create a temporary file, write the 500GB minus a few lines to the temporary file then overwrite the original.

Comment: @don_crissti: does it? It's possible, I'm not 100% familiar with sed's inner workings, but the `-i` option in the manual says: "edit files in place". I always assumed that meant it would just modify the file without having to create a copy.

Comment: As Don says. `sed -i ...` is equivalent to `sed ... file >tmpfile && mv tmpfile file`.  Removing lines from a file in place (properly) is not possible as the length of the file changes.

Comment: @Kusalananda: huh, okay. Learned something new, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer even though it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By using the tail command in that way:

```
# tail -n +<lines to skip> filename
```

for example:

```
tail -n +1000 hugefile.txt > hugefile-wo-the-first-1000-lines.txt
```

And that's all.-
For more information: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail

BTW: Don't be fooled if someone tell you this is exactly the opposite what you want to do, I've tested it:

```
$ tail -n +3 /tmp/test 
3
4
5

$ cat /tmp/test 
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP does _not_ want to do.

Comment: this method needs to write 500GB data to the disk, my question is how to in-place remove the first few lines without writing so much data.