# Efficient header replacement for large (10M line) files?

Tags: sed, tail

I am trying to rename the column headers of a large file, and I want to know the most efficient way to do so. Files are in the range of 10M to 50M lines, with ~100 characters per line in 10 columns.

A similar question was asked to remove the first line, and the best answer involved "tail". [Efficient in-place header removing for large files using sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25629/efficient-in-place-header-removing-for-large-files-using-sed)

My guess is:

```
bash-4.2$ seq -w 100000000 1 125000000 > bigfile.txt
bash-4.2$ tail -n +2 bigfile.txt > bigfile.tail && sed '1 s/^/This is my first line\n/' bigfile.tail > bigfile.new && mv -f bigfile.new bigfile.txt;
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: If you have an old heading that is exactly the same size as the new heading, a very fast replacement is possible.

Comment: The heading will have the same number of columns (ie separators eg \t) but not the same number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have a new header output to a new file, e.g. `printf "This is my first line\n > bigfile.new`.
2. Use the `tail` of the `bigfile` to supply the rest using append redirection: `>>`.

One remark: `tail +2` is "GNUism" - will work on most Linux distribution, but is not POSIX compliant, and will probably not work on other Unices.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `bash` and Linux, this is probably faster than the code in your question:

```
(echo "New headers";tail +2 bigfile.txt) > newbigfile.txt && mv newbigfile.txt bigfile.txt
```